# Regarding java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to write the regular expression with the following conditions:

1. Minimum 8 maximum 64 character
2. Must have 1 character and 1 number
3. Special characters allowed ! @ # $ % ^ & * . ; : {} []

Can you please help?

Below is the expression I tried

```regex
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*.:;{}[\\]]).{8,64})
```

Comment: Don't use a regex for that. And this looks like a password policy - stop using one.

Comment: @luk2302 Then What you want me to go with ?

Comment: @ManjuShankar I don't have a problem with a password policy per se, but you might want to make it a bit stronger than this.  Currently, the password `A1234567` would pass the check (and how many people use this password on their luggage?).

Comment: @ManjuShankar Separate the conditions into their own tests, so that you can provide feedback on _why_ a password is bad (not that I agree with these requirements) and not just ‘*invalid password*’.

Answer (score 2):

A standard way of doing this would use positive lookaheads to assert the presence of a character and a number:

```
^(?=[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])(?=\D*\d)[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*.;:{}\[\]]{8,64}$
```

### Demo

This pattern says to:

```
^                                       from the start of the password
    (?=[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])              assert that a single character appears
    (?=\D*\d)                           assert that a single digit appears
    [A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&*.;:{}\[\]]{8,64}  then match 8-64 valid characters
                                        (letters, numbers, special characters)
$                                       end of password
```